# Which is faster powershell or c# to create bulk user in AD?

Tags: c#, powershell

I want to create bulk users(without using CSV) in Active Directory with more than 10 attributes.So what I have to prefer to create either via powershell or c# to make the **execution** in a faster and better way.

Comment: Which is faster http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: I guess it would depend on how quickly you can code in each, I would of said its fairly easy to create the accounts from AD and use the cmdlets that are already present. If you prefer C# I doubt there would be much stopping you and there would be more than one way to create them including being able to leverage powershell from C#

Comment: Personally I would say powershell but I may be biased since I am not fluent with c#

Comment: I'd agree with Luke, How many accounts are you looking at doing out of curiosity and would you have a need to do it again in the future or is this a one off?

Comment: From what I've heard from fellow Powershellers (but not yet encountered myself) is that the AD cmdlets can be slow with bulk actions : slower then then using the .net classes directly (probably because of the need of the AD web gateway). The simplest way to test it is to write 1 PS script that uses set-Aduser and 1 that uses directorysearcher or accountmanagement and test them with the measure-command cmdlet.

Comment: The question is ambiguous. Faster to write or faster to execute? Like others have already pointed out, code writing speed depends entirely on your proficiency level with the PL. As for performance... compiled code uses less resources and is generally faster than interpreted but if you hit a bottleneck somewhere (e.g. disk I/O) the difference may be negligible. If you have a lot of accounts to add and time is important, think about parallelization via PowerShell jobs or C# Parallel.Foreach.

Comment: @AlexanderObersht,which one is faster to execute?

Comment: @NickEagle, i want to create more than 50 accounts and also repeat the same in future(make use of that code in an windows app.)

Comment: 50 accounts!? Don't bother. Do you think you will ever note any difference in speed???

Answer (score 1):

It's not going to matter which way you do it, the difference isn't going to be minutes or hours... We're talking seconds, C# technically would be quicker.

The question really should be... How are you intending to fill the attributes out if not with a csv, are you looking to create a number of temporary accounts with similar names and attributes?

Because if it's not with a csv or accounts with similar attributes then it would be no quicker than using ADUC.